How to categorise Docusaurus pages regardless of the folder structure?
TLDR; I would like to categorised my .md files regardless of the repo folder structure.
I'm using an ID naming convention for my .md files. For an easy access when I edit the files, I would like to keep them at the same hierarchy level (no subfolders). For the final user, I would like to categorise them in the sidebar. I tried to play with path from the page metadata already but that doesn't effect the sidebar.
This is my repo folder structure:
docs/
  id_01.md
  id_02.md
  id_03.md
  id_04.md

And this is the output I would like to see on the docusaurus sidebar:
Category A
  - My awesome title             (id_01.md)
  - A second cool title          (id_03.md)
Category B
  - Yet another title            (id_02.md)
  - Title, again                 (id_04.md)

